# Drupal views contextual filter taxonomy term id and url alias

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

Views contextual filter 'Content: Has taxonomy term ID' work perfectly, when I try to access it by url like /taxonomy/term/123. It means ID is 123. But I created url aliases for terms. And now I want views get work with alias. Ex.: when I access the page /london/cars/bmw/ it shows taxonomy term 'BMW'

Comment: I found solution. All you need is to not change /taxonomy/term/% path. And then, url alias will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), it will let you define patterns for URL aliases including taxonomy terms.

Comment: There is no problem to create alias. The problem is in views. How can I say views to use Alias as Context filter?

Comment: Likewise I'm using pathauto but some of my taxonomy terms have special characters, like question marks, which get stripped by pathauto and how no way of being processed correctly in a view's contextual filter.

Comment: Pathauto doesn't support views.